# Empty UITableView in UIView with Custom Delegate Class UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been searching a lot on the Internet to get this to work but with no success. The problem is that the custom `UITableViewCell` is not showing the data in the `UITableView`.

I have a custom `UIViewController` that's added into an view:

[image: UITableView that is added from designer]

This view is controlled by a custom `UIViewController` named as `tvResults`:

```
class NavSearchViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tvResults: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ntvc = NavSearchTableViewController();
        tvResults.register(UINib(nibName: "NavSearchResultTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle(for: NavSearchViewController.self)), forCellReuseIdentifier: "NavSearchResultTableViewCell")

        tvResults.dataSource = ntvc
        tvResults.delegate = ntvc

        tvResults.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The class `NavSearchTableViewController` does the simple work as this:

```
class NavSearchTableViewController: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NavSearchResultTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as!NavSearchResultTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

When I'm debugging I can see that it reaches 5 times `cellForRowAt indexPath` without any crash.

The custom cell does look like this:

[image]

All this will end to an empty tableView without any runtime errors or crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have not made any outlet of the cell's label in `NavSearchResultTableViewCell` and not even assigned it a value in `cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath` method like cell.titleLabel.text="someText"

Comment: That's true, but I don't have to set the value defined in the `NavSearchResultTableViewCell` to show it. The complete cell doesn't show up. I tried to change the `numberOfRowsInSection ` to 500, but the `UITableView` didn't change it's view. It still shows an empty `UITableView`